# Set Currency independent of language via dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am having a futher issue here.

I want to have a dropdown with currency the part of selection and identifying which works

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SetCurrency(IFormCollection forms,string returnUrl)
{
    string storeLocale = forms["customerCurrency"].ToString();

    var record = _context.Currencies.Where(w => w.DisplayLocale == storeLocale).FirstOrDefault();

    var currentLanguageId = _context.Appsettings.Where(w => w.Key == Constants.FrontEndDefaultLanguageId).FirstOrDefault();
    if (record != null)
    {
        _config[Constants.FrontEndDefaultLanguageId] = record.Id.ToString();
        currentLanguageId.Value = record.Id.ToString();
        _context.SaveChanges();
        _toast.AddAlertToastMessage("Currecy changed to " + record.Name); 
    }           
        
    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
}
```

For my culture I am doing this which is control by the language dropdown

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SetCulture(string culture, string returnUrl)
{
    var record = _context.Appsettings.Where(w => w.Key == Constants.FrontEndDefaultLanguageId).FirstOrDefault();
        if (culture == "en")
            record.Value = "1";

        if (culture == "fr")
            record.Value = "2";
        _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        _toast.AddSuccessToastMessage("Language changed to :" + record.Key);

        Response.Cookies.Append(
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
            new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1) }
        );
        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
 }
```

I don't want SetCurrency to override what has been set in the cookie but i want it to set if it would use the euro pound symbol etc so I think I need Number Info but am not sure how I would set it in this case.

Image showing issue of symbol at present setting currency causes this cause the system does not no which currency to use yet.

[image]

My two drop downs are like this. For example a french man might be living in uk but has to by the item in pounds.

[image]

This is my form for reference

```
<form id="SetCurrency"
          asp-controller="Warehouse"
          asp-action="SetCurrency"
          asp-route-returnUrl="@returnUrl"
          method="post"
          class="form-horizontal nav-link text-dark"
          role="form">
          <select id="customerCurrency" name="customerCurrency" asp-items="@currencies"   
                  onchange="this.form.submit();" aria-label="@T("Currency.Selector.Label")">

    </select> 
 </form>
```

Comment: According to your description, the Culture DropDownList is used to select the language, and it will store the selected culture using cookie. For the Currency Dropdownlist, when display or insert item with a price, it is used to select the Currency. They should be completely independent. You could create a Currencies table to store the Currency, and for the product table (contains Price property), you could add a foreign key to select currency type, then when insert or display the price, you could based on the foreign currency key to set Currency symbol.

Comment: @ZhiLv I already no it should be independent and that I need the currency symbol you answer does not add anything meanfull to the request !